# I am trying to get user repos from github

Tags: jquery, github

I am trying to get user repos from github. The code I'm using it isn't working

Here is where I am trying to implement it. http://codeforu.ms/staff/matthew/#ourTab

Its working in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wh1t3w0lf21/nT5wY/3/

And here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn_get_repos").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/google/repos",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            for( i in result ) {
                $("#repo_list").append(
                    "<li><a href='" + result[i].html_url + "' target='_blank'>" +
                    result[i].name + "</a></li>"
                );
                console.log("i: " + i);
            }
            console.log(result);
            $("#repo_count").append("Total Repos: " + result.length);
        }
    });
});
    </script>

<li id="ourTab" class="profileContent">
    <div id="repos">
        <ul id="repo_list"></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="repo_content"></div>
    <button id="btn_get_repos">Get Repos</button><span id="repo_count"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Oh. I can't get it to work.

Comment: What should work? how should it work?

Comment: Look at the js fiddle I put there

Comment: what is the code doing and what do you expect?

Comment: It should return a list of a users repo

Comment: Can someone look at the js fiddle, then look at my code and tell me why it isnt working?

Comment: Wrap your event subscriber in ready function $(function() { // js here }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just subscribing to the event before the dom is ready. Just wrap it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn_get_repos").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://api.github.com/users/google/repos",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                for (i in result) {
                    $("#repo_list").append(
                    "<li><a href='" + result[i].html_url + "' target='_blank'>" + 
                    result[i].name + "</a></li>"
                    );
                    console.log("i: " + i);
                }
                console.log(result);
                $("#repo_count").append("Total Repos: " + result.length);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks!!! Also do you know if it is possible to list the repositories without having to click that button?

Comment: Do you just want to list them when the page loads? Just remove the event click subscription and do it on page ready.